# Codeigniter error :fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm getting some error *fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known* when sending mail using phpmailer.

I have two domains. When I try to send mail from my demo domain `https://www.cad180.com/karistore.in/get-free-quote`, the email I received successfully but when I try to do the same thing from original domain `https://www.karistore.in/get-free-quote` is saying message has been sent but in dev panel network zone it's showing *fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known*.

I've downloaded the code from karistore.in and uploaded the same to my demo server. Again demo server sending the mail but original server giving an error.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?